# Use replace with in clause

Tags: mysql

Got ids stored in DB with Json format like this

```
'[&quot;1454&quot;,&quot;474&quot;,&quot;545&quot;]'
```

I can build list IDs :

```
SELECT replace
 (replace(
   replace(
     replace('[&quot;1454&quot;,&quot;474&quot;,&quot;545&quot;]','[','\'')
     ,']','\'')
   ,'&quot;','')    
,',','\',\'')
```

mySql returns    '1454','474','545'

But when I try to list DB records from this build list of IDs :

```
SELECT col FROM table WHERE col in (REPLACE
  (REPLACE(
REPLACE(
    REPLACE('[&quot;1454&quot;,&quot;474&quot;,&quot;545&quot;]','[','\'')
    ,']','\'')
,'&quot;','')   
,',','\',\''));
```

mySql says "0 records" even if I add a "SELECT" before the first "REPLACE"

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below query, you need to add select in your in clause also:

```
SELECT col FROM table WHERE col in (select REPLACE
  (REPLACE(
REPLACE(
    REPLACE('[&quot;1454&quot;,&quot;474&quot;,&quot;545&quot;]','[','\'')
    ,']','\'')
,'&quot;','')   
,',','\',\''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Alas, you cannot use `in` with a comma delimited *string*.  It takes a list of elements, but not within a string.  So, this works as you expect:

```
where x in (1,2,3)
```

This does not work as you expect (although it does work as I expect0;

```
where x in ('1,2,3')
```

This looks for *one* value of x that is the string `'1,2,3'`.

The solution is to use the MySQL function `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT col
FROM table
WHERE find_in_set(col, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('[&quot;1454&quot;,&quot;474&quot;,&quot;545&quot;]', '[','\''
                                              ), ']', '\''
                                      ), '&quot;', ''
                              ), ',', '\',\''
                 );
```

To be honest, though, you might be better off with something like:

```
where '[&quot;1454&quot;,&quot;474&quot;,&quot;545&quot;]' like concat('%;', col, '&%')
```

Comment: Thanks to you Gordon your last solution works fine replacing '[&quot;1454&quot;,&quot;474&quot;,&quot;545&quot;]' by field name...